# Порядок выполнения содержимого методов doPost и doGet

Tags: tomcat, servlet

Есть такой метод:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ...
        response.getWriter().write("ok");
        MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
        myclass.doSomething();
        ...
```

Всегда `ok` возвращается лишь после того, как всё остальное выполнится. Например, когда метод `doSomething()` закончит свою работу. 
Например, мне нужно сразу дать ответ `ok` и сделать так, чтобы клиент не ожидал больше ответа и не было `connection timeout`-а, а уж выполнится метод или нет - другой вопрос.
Пытался сунуть выполнение всего остального в отдельный поток - тогда `ok` возвращалось моментально и ожидания не происходило, однако метод выполнялся через какой-то непонятный рандомный промежуток времени, а не сразу.
То есть необходимо сделать так, чтобы мой сервер сразу давал ответ, но я мог запустить какие-то методы так, чтобы они тоже в эту же секунду начали выполняться, но чтобы клиент не ожидал их окончания. 
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл следующий способ, опробовал, на первый взгляд всё работает:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
...
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

os.write("ok".getBytes("UTF-8"));
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
response.setContentLength(2);

os.close();

/* 
 * И далее можно делать что угодно, 
 * клиент ожидать окончания всех действий не будет 
 */
}
```

В течение секунды даётся ответ, коннекшн закрывается, клиент ответа не ждёт. Однако, волнение некоторое осталось: безопасно ли так делать, и так далее. Возможные ошибки на серверной части я в учёт не беру, ибо исправляю я их в любом случае, но вот чтобы "клиент" знал об этом, мне не нужно, пусть для него в любой ситуации ответом будет `200 ОК`.

По сути, на свой вопрос я ответил, но если кто-либо его дополнит или укажет на подводные камни и прочее, буду крайне благодарен.