# Ограничение времени выполнения метода в основном потоке

Tags: java

Есть некоторая проблема - работаю с одним API примерно следующим образом:

```
событие -> 
запрос от их API к моему серверу -> 
[какие-то действия -> мой запрос к их API (или несколько)] ->
на основе их ответа уже мой ответ их запросу
```

Так вот, действия, происходящие в [квадратных скобках] могут выполняться очень долго (как ни странно, в виду долгого их ответа, а не моего). Несмотря на это, после 20 или 25 секунд, примерно, их сервер перестаёт ждать моего ответа.

Что мне нужно сделать:

```
событие ->
запрос от их API к моему серверу -> 
я запускаю обработку запроса, 
которая должна длиться не более 20 секунд,
если дольше - возвращаю дефолтный ответ ->
[какие-то действия -> мой запрос к их API (или несколько)] ->
на основе их ответа уже мой ответ их запросу
```

То есть нужно сделать так, чтобы при превышении времени обработки, я давал дефолтный ответ. 
Я не хочу уменьшать сам время ожидания, и так далее, мне нужно сделать именно так, как я описал, не меняя ничего остального в коде.

Я могу всю свою обработку сунуть в переопределённый `run()` нового потока, и за`join()`ить его, и как [в этом примере](http://www.cyberforum.ru/post1384389.html), интерраптить через определенное количество секунд. Но это крайне небезопасно, и всё такое прочее. К тому же, во время выполнения, я и к базе данных обращаюсь, и сам запросы какие-то делаю.

Буду рад, если подскажете возможное решение.

---

Немного конкретики, если вдруг кто решит уточнить:

Работаю с VK Callback API, во время обработки их запросов, появляется необходимость скачать аватар пользователя или ещё некоторые файлы. То есть, я обращаюсь к файлу по URL и скачиваю его на диск следующим образом (не спрашивайте, почему так, а не с использованием библиотек апачей):

```
public void downloadFile(String fileURL, String saveFilePath) {
    try {
        int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
        URL url = new URL(fileURL);
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

        // always check HTTP response code first
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

            // opens input stream from the HTTP connection
            InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();

            // opens an output stream to save into file
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath);

            int bytesRead;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        }
        httpConn.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Или же просто считываю картинку с URL:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://..."));
```

И постоянно ошибки, либо такая (ссылается на строчку, приведенную чуть выше):

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't get input stream from URL!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1395)
```

Либо такая:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
```

Которая ссылается на эту строчку:

```
int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
```

Такое случается не всегда, и только последнее время, + было еще чуть больше недели назад. Но сейчас уже два дня подряд, причем постоянно, и с этим надо как-то бороться. Пробовал добавлять User-Agent, вдруг в этом проблема, но это тоже не помогает. Да и вычислить, помогает это или нет, довольно трудно, потому что эта ошибка выскакивает когда хочет, и приходится повторять действия неоднократно, чтобы понять, решена проблема или нет.

Comment: Разве [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799938/httpurlconnection-timeout-question) в первом ответе не то что нужно? Устанавливаете нужный timeout, затем по SocketTimeoutException отправляете дефолтный ответ.

Comment: @iksuy у меня стоит время ожидания большее, нежели у самого ВК, да и некоторые действия, которые я выполняю, могут длиться секунд 5-10, и лишь после них последует мой запрос. Не ставить же мне время ожидания в 5 секунд. Поэтому предложенный вами способ вряд ли подойдет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку на первый вопрос мне изначально не ответили, я решил его переформулировать и задать этот вопрос. Отвечаю на вторую часть своего вопроса: мне нужно было сделать так, чтобы клиент не ждал окончания выполнения всех моих действий. На этот вопрос я ответил тут: [Порядок выполнения содержимого методов doPost и doGet](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/686230/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2-dopost-%D0%B8-doget)